# Maximal normal locally nilpotent subgroup in an infinite extension of a Prüfer group

Tags: group-theory, semidirect-product, nilpotence, infinite-groups

Let $P$ be a Prüfer $p$-group, let $x$ be an infinite automorphism of $P$, namely a $p$-adic unit, and consider the semidirect product $G$ between $P$ and $\langle x\rangle$ via the action of $x$ on $P$. Find the maximal (normal) locally nilpotent subgroup of $G$.

Now, I know that such a subgroup is not $P$ itself, but I hardly see how to find a bigger, locally nilpotent subgroup of $G$, given the fact that $x$ (or any of its powers) could not centralize $P$.

Comment: How do you know that it is not $P$ itself?

Comment: There is this result by Robinson [Finiteness Conditions, Theorem 3.32] which in particular says that if a soluble group has its maximal locally nilpotent normal subgroup satisfying the minimal condition on its subgroups, then the same condition is satisfied by the group itself. Here $G$ is clearly not Min.

Comment: In fact $G$ itself is locally nilpotent, because its finitely generated subgroups intersect $P$ in a finite subgroup.

Comment: Let $P=Z_{3^\infty}$, $1\neq a\in Soc(P)\simeq Z_3$ and let $a^x=a^{-1}$. Then wouldn't $\langle a,x\rangle/\langle x^2\rangle$ be isomorphic with the symmetric group of degree $3$, being hence non-nilpotent? Where am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, sorry, if $a^x = a^{-1}$, then the maximal locally nilpotent subgroup is $\langle P, x^2 \rangle$, which has index $2$ in $G$. In general, it could be $\langle P,x^k \rangle$, where $k$ divides $p-1$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Could we say that, laying $x^{p-1}$ in $C_G(Soc(G))$, it has to centralize the whole $P$?
This should be true because of the action of the infinite automorphisms of Prüfer $p$-groups, which have to act coherently on each term of the socle series of the $p$-group. In this case the maximal locally nilpotent subgroup would be even abelian.

Comment: No, we can't. Clearly, $x$ could act as $1$ on $Soc(P)$ and as $p+1$ on the second socle of $G$!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) If $x\equiv 1\mod p$ (which is automatic for $p=2$), then then the whole group $G=P\rtimes\langle x\rangle$ is locally nilpotent (because modulo $p^n$ $x$ belongs to the kernel of $(\mathbf{Z}/p^n\mathbf{Z})^\ast\to(\mathbf{Z}/p\mathbf{Z})^*$, which is a $p$-group.

(2) If $x\equiv\!\!\!\!/ 1\mod p$, then $G=P\rtimes\langle x\rangle$ is not locally nilpotent, because its finite subquotient $((\mathbf{Z}/p\mathbf{Z})\rtimes\langle x\rangle)/\langle x^{p-1}\rangle$ is finite and not nilpotent (as its $p$-Sylow is abelian and not central).

In general, consider the residual ring homomorphism $\mathbf{Z}_p\to\mathbf{Z}/p\mathbf{Z}$ and let $k$ be the order of the image of $x$ in $(\mathbf{Z}/p\mathbf{Z})^*$. Then (1) implies that the normal subgroup $P\rtimes\langle x^k\rangle$ is locally nilpotent. A subgroup properly containing the latter has the form $P\rtimes\langle x^\ell\rangle$ where $\ell$ properly divides $k$. By (2), it is not locally nilpotent. We conclude that:

> The locally nilpotent radical of $G=P\rtimes\langle x\rangle$ is equal to $P\rtimes\langle x^k\rangle$, where $k$ is the order of the image of $x$ in $(\mathbf{Z}/p\mathbf{Z})^*$.

---

Edit: I initially claimed that the Fitting subgroup (generated by nilpotent normal subgroups) is the same. As pointed out by Alex, it's not true. Although it's not part of the question, let me include the description:

> The Fitting subgroup of $G=P\rtimes\langle x\rangle$ is equal to $P\rtimes\langle x^\ell\rangle (=P\rtimes\times \langle x^\ell\rangle)$, where $\ell$ is the order of $x$ in $\mathbf{Z}_p^*$, which when $\ell=\infty$ is meant to denote $P$.

Indeed, this is a normal abelian subgroup, hence contained in the Fitting subgroup. Any subgroup properly containing the latter one has the form $P\rtimes\langle x^n\rangle$ with $x^n\neq 1$. This is not nilpotent: indeed, we have $[x^n,\mathbf{Q}_p]=\mathbf{Q}_p$, and this passes to the quotient $P=\mathbf{Q}_p/\mathbf{Z}_p$ to yield $[x^n,P]=P$.

Comment: What do you mean by "the order of $x$ modulo $p$"? Are you talking about $\langle x\rangle$ as a finite group?
Anyway there is something I don't understand. For instance, in (2) $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})\rtimes\langle x\rangle/\langle x^p\rangle$ is a $p$ group and hence a nilpotent group.

Comment: Maybe you are talking about the order of $x$ seen as an automorphism of $Soc(P)$, is that so? (My objection against point (2) stands anyway)

Comment: @AlexDoe thanks for your comments. I didn't realize it's ambiguous; by "order of $x$ modulo $p$" I meant "order of the image of $x$ in $(\mathbf{Z}/p\mathbf{Z})^*$". It's fixed now. Second, you're right about (2): I had to mod out by $x^{p-1}$ (which is central), not $x^p$. The subgroup generated by $x^p$ is not normal in this case. It's fixed too.

Comment: Ok, I think everything you said is right, maybe except for the fact that the locally nilpotent radical would coincide with the Fitting subgroup. For example, even in the case in which $P\rtimes\langle x\rangle$ is the locally dihedral $2$-group (hence case (1), quotiented by $\langle x^2\rangle$), $\langle x\rangle$ would be ascending but not subnormal, thus not contained in any nilpotent normal subgroup of $G$. I think that the Fitting subgroup is always $P$, for every non-trivial action of $x$ on $P$. Apart from this, I believe everything is correct!

Comment: I guess that the only case in which the two radicals coincide is when $x\equiv 1\mod p^n$ for each $n$, namely, when the action of $x$ on $P$ is trivial.

Comment: @AlexDoe thanks very much, it's fixed now; I gave a statement, since when $x$ has finite order the Fitting subgroup is still larger than $P$. The Fitting subgroup coincides with the locally nilpotent radical iff $x$ has the same multiplicative order as its reduction modulo $p$.